# Sum duplicated objects in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an unsorted array of objects with CustomerId, ProductId and Count (all ints)
I want to combine records where CustomerId and ProductId match, summing the count.

for example:

```
CId  PId  Cnt
1    100  5
1    100  1
2    100  7
```

Desired output:

```
CId  PId  Cnt
1    100  6
2    100  7
```

As you can see for the two records for CId 1 & PId 100 have been merged and the count has been summed.

Can this be done with LINQ?
I know it could done with loops but I'm hoping for a more elegant way

Comment: Look into `GroupBy` and `Sum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I have assumed that the class name is `Item`:

```
var result = array.GroupBy(x => new { x.CId, x.PId })
   .Select(g => new Item { CId = g.Key.CId, PId = g.Key.PId, Cnt = g.Sum(x => x.Cnt) });
```

Here is a [**Live Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dJkj3g)